# Upload a Sound File using SoundCloud API with raw Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, soundcloud

I want to Upload a Sound File using SoundCloud API with raw Javascript.

I write the following code:

```
var url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json"; 

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var formData = new FormData( form );
formData.append( "access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN );


xhr.open( "POST", url, true );

xhr.onload = somAdicionado;

xhr.send( formData );
```

but I'm getting the error

```
{"errors":[{"error_message":"401 - Unauthorized"}]}
```

To obtain the access_token I use the following code:

```
SC.connect(function() {
    SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
      alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
    });
    ACCESS_TOKEN = SC.accessToken();  // Obtem o access_token 
});
```

And I have the HTML Form:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" >    

                <label>Escolha o ficheiro de som</label>
                <input name="asset_data" type="file" >

                <label>Descreva o som</label>
                <input id="descricaoSom" name="title" type="text" value="">

            <input type="submit" id="uploadSound" value="Upload Sound"/>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party here, but my understanding is that the API looks for "client_id" in the URL, not "access_token".

```
 var url = `${track.stream_url}?client_id=${MYCLIENTID}`;
```

*ES6, need Traceur right now.